# I'm trying to store a large amount of data and I want it to be accessable in the app that my users download

Tags: arrays, core-data

So I have an array of a couple hundred universities and I want my users to be able to select one. I have tried storing data in firebase database and then requesting the data, but firebase is just awful with arrays, I have tried calling some api, but I didn't like how they didn't work how I wanted. So now I'm trying to do it with local storage (like Core Data), but all the implementations that I have seen right now only have the user add data. I want to store the array and I want every user to have access to it.

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to be so locked in to having an array, if you persist  items in a database table then you are better of storing each item by itself and then you can add them to an array when you load them into your code.

Comment: Also, if this data is not editable by the user, and there is just a handful of data in each entry (name, address, etc.), Core Data is overkill.  Put it in a .plist file in your app's resources.

Comment: OK, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can write tool to add data into model file or create core data empty store and add data manually.

After populating data grab the file and add it into your project.